# Show whether this trigonometry series converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin\left(\frac{3n}{1+3^n}\right)$

Kinda obvious that it converges, but how do I prove it mathematically?

Comment: $$\le\dfrac{3n}{3^n}$$

Comment: By saying "it is obvious" :D

Comment: What is the precise meaning of "kinda" (english is not my mother's language) ?

Comment: @JeanMarie 'sort of'

Comment: Thanks. I should have guessed...

Answer (score 2):

First show that $0 \le \sin(x) \le x$ for $x \in [0,1]$, so if the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3n}{1+3^n}$ converges, you have a bound of your original series, and thus we can compute the latter series instead of the original series.
Then we have $0 \le \frac{3n}{1+3^n} \le \frac{3n}{3^n}$ as $3^n \le 1+3^n$, so we can, with the same argument as before, compute $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3n}{3^n}$ instead of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3n}{1+3^n}$.
And this sum converges as it is $\frac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}x} \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n$ for $x= \frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: The idea is good and surely not deserves downmarking! The only term that is slightly incorrect is "compute... instead". No, you bound from above a positive series by another positive series which is convergent as you establish it

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: @JeanMarie Since you bound a positive sequence by another sequence, you can compute the second serie, and if that converges, the first one converges. So you do compute ... instead of the first one. But I will rephrase it to make it better.

Comment: Is it better phrased this way?

Comment: @Hetebrij Yes, we are on the same wavelength: It is just the verb "bound" that was lacking... The term "compute instead" still sounds me unusual in a mathematical reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Note that $\dfrac{\sin x}x\to1$ when $x\to0$.

Answer (score 0):

You get rid of the sine by using $\sin(x)\le x$, then simplify a little with $\dfrac{3n}{1+3^n}<\dfrac{3n}{3^n}$. You are now close to a (converging) geometric series.

By induction, $n<\left(\dfrac32\right)^n$ because for $n>2$,

$$n+1<\frac32n<\frac32\cdot\left(\frac32\right)^n=\left(\frac32\right)^{n+1}.$$

Then the general term of the series is bounded by

$$\frac3{2^n}.$$